# BETWEEN Two Dates is Returning Rows of the Same Two Dates instead of the Ones Between

Tags: sql, oracle, select, between

I'm trying to select rows that are between two specific dates, but I'm getting the rows that are of the same dates specified in  `BETWEEN`  instead. I tried using operators > and <, but nothing seems to work. Does it have to do with the date format?

```
SELECT  r.RESERVATION_ID, a.AGENT_ID, a.AGENT_FNAME AS AGENT_NAME, t.TRIP_ID,
s.RESERVATION_STATUS

FROM RESERVATION r 
INNER JOIN AGENT a
ON
a.AGENT_ID=r.AGENT_ID

INNER JOIN TOURTRIP_RESERVATION t
ON
r.RESERVATION_ID=t.RESERVATION_ID

INNER JOIN RESERVATION_STATUS s
ON
r.RESERVATION_STATUSID=s.RESERVATION_STATUSID

WHERE r.AGENT_ID IS NOT NULL
AND r.RESERVATION_DATE BETWEEN '15-MAR-20' AND '26-MAY-20'
AND r.RESERVATION_STATUSID=100;
```

I used `to_date('03.06.2020','DD.MM.YYYY')` format to update the data in the reservation_id column. However, when I use

```
and RESERVATION_DATE > to_date('15.03.2020','DD.MM.YYYY') 
and RESERVATION_DATE < to_date('26.05.2020','DD.MM.YYYY')
```

it's returning nothing

This is the reservation table

[image]

Comment: Is your RESERVATION_DATE column is in date datatype?

Comment: indeed it is. This is how I added the dates TO_DATE('26-MAY-20')

Comment: Hi, can you let us know what are the results of this query, `SELECT value
FROM   nls_database_parameters
WHERE  parameter = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT'`

Comment: Hi, thank you for the suggestion. I shall get back to you tomorrow as the server has shutdown for the day. Cheers

Comment: In case it helps, date literals are written like this: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Literals.html#GUID-8F4B3F82-8821-4071-84D6-FBBA21C05AC1

Comment: The result of `SELECT value FROM nls_database_parameters WHERE parameter = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT'` is DD-MON-RR

Answer (score 2):

The condition **between** includes the start and the end.
You can use the operators > and < to exclude it.

Your example simplified:

```
create table RESERVATION (
 RESERVATION_ID number
,RESERVATION_DATE date)
```

Data:

```
insert into RESERVATION values (1, to_date('01.06.2020','DD.MM.YYYY'));
insert into RESERVATION values (2, to_date('02.06.2020','DD.MM.YYYY'));
insert into RESERVATION values (3, to_date('03.06.2020','DD.MM.YYYY'));
```

Query A)

```
select RESERVATION_ID 
  from RESERVATION
 where RESERVATION_DATE between to_date('01.06.2020','DD.MM.YYYY') 
                            and to_date('03.06.2020','DD.MM.YYYY')
```

will return:

```
1
2
3
```

The Query B)

```
select RESERVATION_ID 
  from RESERVATION
 where RESERVATION_DATE > to_date('01.06.2020','DD.MM.YYYY') 
   and RESERVATION_DATE < to_date('03.06.2020','DD.MM.YYYY')
```

will return

```
2
```

I assume that *RESERVATION_DATE* is a date. Use always explicit datatype conversion.

Answer (score 0):

If `RESERVATION_DATE` column's datatype is `DATE`, don't compare it to strings, because `'15-MAR-20'` is a string. Oracle will try to implicitly convert it to a valid date value; sometimes it'll succeed, sometimes it'll return false value (as its NLS settings differ from what you provided), and sometimes it'll fail and raise an error.

These two:

- `date '2020-03-15'`
- `to_date('15.03.2020', 'dd.mm.yyyy')`

on the other hand, are **dates**.

`BETWEEN` is *inclusive* and will return both *limits*, if they exist:

```
AND r.RESERVATION_DATE BETWEEN date '2020-03-15' and date '2020-05-26'
```

If you want to *exclude* those limits, then

```
AND r.RESERVATION_DATE > date '2020-03-15'
AND r.RESERVATION_DATE < date '2020-05-26'
```

---

But, if `RESERVATION_DATE` is a `VARCHAR2` column, you're doing a big mistake. Never store dates as strings. If you can't afford modifying datatype, then you'll have to convert it to date:

```
and to_date(r.reservation_date, 'dd-mon-yy') between date '2020-03-15'
                                                 and date '2020-05-26'
```

This *will work* as long as there aren't any invalid values in that column. Because, as it is a string, you can put something like `15-AA-2F` which certainly isn't a date, but can be stored into such a column. In that case, query will fail and you'll have to fix data.

---

Comment you posted says that you tried `TO_DATE('26-MAY-20')`. That's not enough - you should provide format mask as that can be

- 26th of May 2020
- 20th of May 2026

and it depends on NLS settings. Furthermore, it'll fail in my database:

Because NLS settings are different:

```
SQL> select to_date('26-may-20') from dual;
select to_date('26-may-20') from dual
               *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected
```

Because we don't have "may" in Croatia:

```
SQL> select to_date('26-may-20', 'dd-mon-yy') from dual;
select to_date('26-may-20', 'dd-mon-yy') from dual
               *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01843: not a valid month
```

But this works, as I told Oracle what I want:

```
SQL> select to_date('26-may-20', 'dd-mon-yy', 'nls_date_language = english') from dual;

TO_DATE('26-MAY-20'
-------------------
26.05.2020 00:00:00
```

Even better, use digits only or date literal (which is always a `date 'yyyy-mm-dd'`):

```
SQL> select to_date('26.05.2020', 'dd.mm.yyyy') d1,
  2         date '2020-05-26' d2
  3  from dual;

D1                  D2
------------------- -------------------
26.05.2020 00:00:00 26.05.2020 00:00:00

SQL>
```

---

Based on sample data you provided, presuming that `reservation_date` column's datatype is `date`:

- setting environment first
- sample data is from line #1 - 9
- query you need begins at line #10

Here you go:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_language = 'english';

Session altered.

SQL> alter session set nls_Date_format = 'dd-mon-yy';

Session altered.

SQL> with reservation (reservation_id, reservation_date, agent_id) as
  2    (select 8576, date '2020-03-15', 222  from dual union all
  3     select 7325, date '2020-05-26', 333  from dual union all
  4     select 3186, date '2020-04-23', 111  from dual union all
  5     select 8000, date '2020-04-05', 555  from dual union all
  6     select 4120, date '2020-01-03', null from dual union all
  7     select 1546, date '2020-02-15', null from dual union all
  8     select 1007, date '2020-05-06', null from dual
  9    )
 10  select *
 11  from reservation
 12  where reservation_date between date '2020-03-15'
 13                             and date '2020-05-26'
 14  order by reservation_date;

RESERVATION_ID RESERVATI   AGENT_ID
-------------- --------- ----------
          8576 15-mar-20        222
          8000 05-apr-20        555
          3186 23-apr-20        111
          1007 06-may-20
          7325 26-may-20        333

SQL>
```

Comment: Alright. I will update the table with the new date format because I used TO_DATE('26-MAY-20') to populate the reservation_date column and try the query again

Comment: As I said: that's not enough. Re-read the last part of my answer.

Comment: I've edited  the question with the update and results

Comment: And I edited the answer by adding example based on your sample data. Have a look, please.

Comment: I followed the exact steps, but nothing's changed. I ran 'SELECT value FROM nls_database_parameters WHERE parameter = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT'' for session before and after and it's still DD-MON-RR. Are RR and YY the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

**I changed the date format, try this and tell me if you have other result.**

```
SELECT  r.RESERVATION_ID, a.AGENT_ID, a.AGENT_FNAME AS AGENT_NAME, t.TRIP_ID,
s.RESERVATION_STATUS

FROM RESERVATION r 
INNER JOIN AGENT a
ON
a.AGENT_ID=r.AGENT_ID

INNER JOIN TOURTRIP_RESERVATION t
ON
r.RESERVATION_ID=t.RESERVATION_ID

INNER JOIN RESERVATION_STATUS s
ON
r.RESERVATION_STATUSID=s.RESERVATION_STATUSID

WHERE r.AGENT_ID IS NOT NULL
AND r.RESERVATION_DATE BETWEEN '2020-03-15' AND '2020-05-26'
AND r.RESERVATION_STATUSID=100;
```

Comment: I'm getting ORA-01861: literal does not match format string. Does it mean I have to update the dates format in the table to much that of the query ?

Comment: Yes, you need to change your date format for your column like my query,